# Python - Building A Nested tree Dynamically

Tags: python, json, algorithm, recursion, tree

I am trying to build a tree hierarchy with python lets say I have his structure, I need to be able to add more children dynamically to e.g `Bannana`.
I think my question is a bit unclear

**UPDATE:** I need to create a structure like this, But The values will change so I need to create function to pass a int and create that amount of  `Apple(Children)` and to to do the same for Lemon and all the other children. Also the Apple node is Root Node.

```
Apple
   Bannana
   Lemon
      Juice
        Drink
   Watermelon
       Red
         Round
```

But then I can Have a totally diffrent strucutre where e.g

```
Apple
   Bannana
   Lemon
      Juice
        Drink
          Watermelon
       Red
          Round
```

Json Ouptut would be

```
{
    'Apple': 'Fruit',
    'children': [{
        'Bannana': 'fruit',
        'children': None
    },  {
        'Lemon': 'Fruit',
        'children': [{
            'Juice': 'Food',
            'children': [{
                'Drink': 'Action',
                'children': None
             And so on...
```

**How can make the hierarchy dynamic? For example the Number of rows under a specific parent?**

I have tried something like that from an example I found

```
import collections
def add_element(root, path, data):
    if len(path) == 1:
        root[path[0]] = data
    else:
        add_element(root[path[0]], path[1:], data)

count = 1


tree = lambda: collections.defaultdict(tree)
root = tree()
n= 10
for i in range(1,n):
    path_list= ['Apple', 'Lemon', 'Juice' + str(count)]
    print (path_list)
    count += 1
    add_element(root,path_list, 1 )
print (root)
```

**EDIT 1**

As per the Answer I have modfied the code a bit

```
args = {'Apple': 'Apple', 'Lemon': 'Lemon', 'Juice': 'Juice', 'Drink': 'Drink'}

s = """
{Apple}
   {Lemon}
      {Juice}
         {Drink}
""".format(**args)

def group_data(vals):
  if len(vals) == 1:
     return {vals[0]:'Fruit', 'Children':None}
  new_data = [list(b) for _, b in itertools.groupby(vals, key=lambda x:bool(re.findall('^\s', x)))]
  new_group = [[new_data[i], new_data[i+1]] for i in range(0, len(new_data), 2)]
  result = []
  for a, b in new_group:
     result.extend([{i:'Fruit', 'Children':None} for i in a[:-1]])
     result.append({a[-1]:'Fruit', 'Children':group_data([re.sub('^\s{3}', '', c) for c in b])})
  return result

_new_data = [i.strip('\n') for i in filter(None, s.split('\n'))]


print(json.dumps(group_data(_new_data), indent=4))
```

this works fine but its still hardcoded which is not what im looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can analyze the whitespace before each fruit:

```
s = """
Apple
   Bannana
   Lemon
      Juice
         Drink
            Watermelon
      Red
         Round
"""
```

---

```
import itertools, re
def group_data(vals):
  if len(vals) == 1:
     return {vals[0]:'Fruit', 'Children':None}
  new_data = [list(b) for _, b in itertools.groupby(vals, key=lambda x:bool(re.findall('^\s', x)))]
  new_group = [[new_data[i], new_data[i+1]] for i in range(0, len(new_data), 2)]
  result = []
  for a, b in new_group:
     result.extend([{i:'Fruit', 'Children':None} for i in a[:-1]])
     result.append({a[-1]:'Fruit', 'Children':group_data([re.sub('^\s{3}', '', c) for c in b])})
  return result

_new_data = [i.strip('\n') for i in filter(None, s.split('\n'))]
```

---

```
import json
print(json.dumps(group_data(_new_data), indent=4))
```

Output:

```
[
     {
       "Apple": "Fruit",
       "Children": [
         {
            "Bannana": "Fruit",
            "Children": null
           },
           {
               "Lemon": "Fruit",
               "Children": [
                  {
                      "Juice": "Fruit",
                       "Children": [
                            {
                             "Drink": "Fruit",
                             "Children": {
                                 "Watermelon": "Fruit",
                                 "Children": null
                              }
                          }
                      ]
                  },
                  {
                       "Red": "Fruit",
                       "Children": {
                          "Round": "Fruit",
                          "Children": null
                     }
                  }
              ]
          }
       ]
    }
]
```

Comment: Thats, a really good answer, but how could i do if I have dynamic values?

Comment: @WojtekT This will work for any valid structure. Can you clarify what you mean by "dynamic values"?

Comment: Dynamically I mean For Example I want to have 10 RootChild Nodes then I want to put in 2 children in every second RootChild Node